# Neither catch statement of promise/block is executing

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code in a worker.

```
var cBtnStore = {
    a: function(){}
};
```

Now notice there is no `b` key in there.

I then have a function in my worker. It does this:

```
function run() {
    ...
    self.postMessageWithCallback(function() {
        cBtnStore.b(); ////// there is no b key, this should prevent going to the return
    });
    ...
    return promise; // returns a promise
}

var gCB = {};
self.postMessageWithCallback = function(aMsgArr, aCB) {
      var gCBID++;
      aMsgArr.push(gCBID);
      gCB[gCBID] = aCB;
      self.postMessage(aMsgArr);
}

self.onmessage = function(msg) {
    var aCBID = msg.data.pop();
    gCB[aCBID].apply(msg.data);
};
```

I then do this in the worker:

```
try {
    run().then(x=>{}, y=>{}).catch(z=>{console.error('promise caught')});
} catch(err) {
     console.log('runComplete threw');
}
console.log('result:', result);
```

**What actually happens** - This logs to console the return value of `runComplete()` which is `"result:" [Promise object]`. Neither `catch` nor `.catch` statements not execute.

**What I was expecting should have happened** - It should have triggered the `catch` statement of the promise or of the `try-catch` block.

**My question** - Is there anyway to make this catch?

Comment: You show us the declaration of `run()` but then you are calling a function with a different name, `runComplete()`. Also, where is `result` declared and assigned a value?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, this code is in a worker. I added more of the code in a simplified way. In trying to simplify it I made that typo. I fixed it. @nnnnnn

Comment: your handler in the 2nd argument for `.then` is handling the error.

Comment: Is self.postMessageWithCallback() doing something asynchronously? If so, the return statement in run() will happen before the callback is called.

Comment: `there is no b key, this should prevent going to the return` - that's a wrong assumption, that error occurs inside an (I assume) asynchronous callback, well after the `return promise` is run

Comment: Thanks all Ill use you're feedback and experiment with it more.

Comment: Please show us where and how that `promise` you return is defined. Looks just like you're not resolving it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks will post it up tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
run().then(x=>{}, y=>{}).catch(z=>{console.error('promise caught')});
```

your argument `y=>{}` actually means "eat all errors". If you want to see errors, you should write

```
run().then(x=>{}).catch(z=>{console.error('promise caught')});
```

Comment: No way! After working with promises for so long I can't believe I hadn't realized that! This fixed it thanks!!